# Indexed View Schemabinding

Tags: view, indexed, schemabinding

I want to create indexed view, any help would be appreciated. I have this:

```
ALTER VIEW vwCF WITH SCHEMABINDING
as  
SELECT
ftt.FTSName
,cf.FTSTypeID
,ftt.SortOrder
,cf.SecTypeID
,st.SecTypeName
,st.SortOrder
IssuanceDate
,Issuance
,Principal
,Interest
,FlowAmounts
,Net
 FROM dbo.CashFlow AS cf
 INNER JOIN dbo.FinancialType AS ftt ON cf.FTSTypeID = ftt.FTSTypeID
 INNER JOIN dbo.SecType AS st ON cf.SecTypeID = st.SecTypeID
 Go
```

If you have any question let me know...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Missed a coma, see

> IssuanceDate

should be

> ,IssuanceDate

---

Add the table alias in front of:

```
,tbl.IssuanceDate
,tbl.Issuance
,tbl.Principal
,tbl.Interest
,tbl.FlowAmounts
,tbl.Net
```

Where `tbl` is the table where the above information is allocated.

(tbl could differ for the fields, check it!).